# Android activity getting stopped

Tags: android-activity

I have a LoginActivity that has a button with a listener method,

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/view_anonymous_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/action_view_anonymous"
                android:onClick="startMain"/>
```

and the method is,

```
public void  startMain(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Navigation.class);
    intent.putExtra("token", "TEST");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When clicking that button I try to start another activity 'Navigation'. The problem is the new activity is being called but never gets focus. The LoginAcivity is appearing again. To debug, I did print the life cycle methods of Navigation, and the flow is,

onStart -> onResume -> onPause -> onStop. I am not sure why Navigation activity is getting stopped. To give some more information, the onCreate() of Navigation sets up a Fragment and loads some data using AsyncTask that is being called properly. Here is my manifest content,

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/bee"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Navigation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        >
    </activity>

</application>
```

I would like to get some pointers to fix this issue.

**Update**

Activity manager seems to start LoginActivity again instead of displaying Navigation. The onCreate() of Navigation sets up a DrawerLayout that has framelayout and fragment. If I change that to a simple LinearLayout with a textview, it works right.

7-29 03:18:35.302      293-293/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.knackforge.pithpicker/.**LoginActivity**} from pid 970

07-29 03:18:35.832      293-554/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.knackforge.pithpicker for activity com.knackforge.pithpicker/.LoginActivity: pid=980 uid=10046 gids={50046, 3003, 1028}

07-29 03:18:40.822      293-309/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.knackforge.pithpicker/.**LoginActivity**: +5s101ms (total +12s951ms)

07-29 03:18:47.052      293-393/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=com.knackforge.pithpicker/.**Navigation** (has extras)} from pid 980

07-29 03:18:49.524      293-304/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=com.knackforge.pithpicker/.**LoginActivity** (has extras)} from pid 980

07-29 03:18:50.052      293-310/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41aa4538 u0 com.knackforge.pithpicker/.Navigation}

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had a another call that started LoginActivity from Navigation based on some condition, so its just my code that had bug :)